# What's the correct way to await multiple websocket objects?

Tags: python, websocket, async-await

The following works, but doesn't scale well to N objects, which is my next step.

```
    async with websockets.connect('ws://192.168.0.176:81') as websocket1: 
        async with websockets.connect('ws://192.168.0.177:81') as websocket2:            
            async with websockets.connect('ws://192.168.0.194:81') as websocket3: 
                datatosend = GetRainbowStripeData(basecolor)
                await websocket1.send(header1+header2+header3+header4+datatosend)
                await websocket2.send(header1+header2+header3+header4+datatosend)
                await websocket3.send(header1+header2+header3+header4+datatosend)
```

Ideally, what I'd like is to be able to open a connection to each of N endpoints (where N is about 20) and then send data to each, catching and managing exceptions as they occur.

But clearly step-nesting 20 "asyncs" isn't the hot ticket!

What's the tidy/elegant way to go about it?

Comment: You don't need to best them, you can combine multiplle context managers in one `with` line. Seperate them by a comma: `with context_manager_1 as cm1, context_manager_2 as cm2, ...:`

Comment: Sounds like you just want to use a `for` loop to loop through each socket you want to send to and `await` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know and cannot figure out the SYNTAX for a "for" loop that does the equivalent of multiple nested "async with as" statements.  Can someone show an example?